# What does the * (star/asterisk) syntax after a yield mean in a recursive generator function?

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

Let's say I've created an ES6 generator

```
function *createFibonacciIterator(a = 0, b = 1) {
  yield b;
  yield *createFib(b, b + a); // <== QUESTION IS ABOUT THIS LINE
}
```

Then I use that generator to get the first 20 results

```
let fibber = createFibonacciIterator();
for (let ii = 0; ii < 20; ii++) {
    console.log(fibber.next());
}
```

If I leave the `*` out of the `yield *createFib(b, b + a);` line things break, which makes sense because I don't want yield an iterator but an actual value.

What's the technical meaning of `*` in the generator?

Comment: The `yield *` delegates to another generator.

Comment: may be yield * flatten the values and concat those into generator function* lazily.

Answer (score 4):

For most cases

```
yield *smth;
```

makes the same thing as

```
for (let x of smth) {
  yield x;
}
```

Comment: This is an OK simplification, but it fails to address what the `yield *generator()` evaluates to, which as it turns out is the end-of-iteration value `return`'ed by the generator object. It also does not correctly represent what happens when the consumer of the generator throws into the generator, etc.

Comment: @torazaburo, could you show an example?

Answer (score 3):

When the `*` is used in the `function` declaration this mean that it is a generator function.

But when it is used as `yield *myGeneratorFunction()`, the definition of the [Ecmascript 262 specification, Section 14.4.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-14.4.14), says that the engine tries to resolve the generator function calling the `next()` method of iterator returned by the generator function.

When the `yield` is used without the `*` (for example, `yield createFibonacci()`), it returns the value of the expression after the yield. In the example is the value returned of the createFibonacci.

Comment: Online spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-14.4.14

Comment: Yes, this is better. Thanks

Comment: This is a bit confused. You say *the next value of the iterator is the returned value of the function*, but `yield` is not a function. It's a keyword, which results in a value. You say "the engine tries to resolve...", but in fact what happens is `myGeneratorFunction` is called as expected, returning an iterable, and `yield *` operates on that as it would any other iterable (such as `[1, 2]`, for example). The generator function has no `next()` method; it is the iterable **returned** by the generator function that has a `next()` function.

Comment: The function that I mention was the createFibonacci and not the yield keyworld. And Yes, it is the iterable returned by the generator that it is going to be resolved. I'll edit to be clear, but it is correct what you say. Thanks.

Comment: Another way of saying what `yield *myGeneratorFunction()` does: it basically runs an generator within your generator (it "delegates" to another generator). For example, if you wanted to combine two iterators into one, you could do:  `yield *genFunction1(); yield *genFunction2()`.  Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*